# ASIHttprequest with Apache CXF Restful webservices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, apache, cxf, asihttprequest

I am working on a project involving Apache CXF at server side providing RESTful webservice, taking in and out in JSON format. At the client side is an Mac OSX app with ASIHTTPRequest and SBJson. I had various issues in the last few days, and was not able to find out a solution.

At server side:

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/testService/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Boolean service1(SomeMetaData metaData)
{
  return this.testMetaData(metaData);
}
```

At client side:

```
NSString *requestURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", serverURL, @"/webServices/rest/testService"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestURLString];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
NSString* jsonMetaData = [[SomeMetaData proxyForJson] JSONRepresentation];

NSMutableData *requestBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[jsonMetaData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setPostBody:requestBody];
[request startAsynchronous];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [request responseString]);
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@", [request error]);
}];
```

The JSON string generated from the metadata object is something like this:

```
{
  "metaData": 
  {
    "name":"test.txt",
    "remoteKey":"4",
    "remoteShare":"test1"
  }
}
```

The client and server are in different physical computer but within the same LAN.

**First issue:**

An error domain error randomly appears in the console. There is no apparent pattern for its appearance, but it's guaranteed to show up with my first attempt.

```
Failed: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x10013a030 {NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x100190cf0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"}
```

**Second issue:**

This appears to be a json parser error which I don't really understand why. The container at the server side and the client side has identical structure.

```
Response for getExistsFileRequest: JAXBException occurred : unexpected element (uri:"", local:"metaData"). Expected elements are <{}someMetaData>. unexpected element (uri:"", local:"metaData"). Expected elements are <{}someMetaData>.
```

This kind of issue appears to be only happen when I have parameters in my request. My other GET web services with no input parameter works perfectly fine.

I have been stucked on this for days. Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

In case anyone is wondering, there is a root path defined for all web services on server side, so it's not likely to be a problem in this case.

**Another edit: ** Request/Response headers at server side

```
[ERROR] 500 - POST /webServices/rest/testService (192.168.1.29) 199 bytes
Request headers
  Host: 192.168.1.206
  User-Agent: ASIHTTPRequest (Macintosh; Mac OS X 10.7.2; en_CA)
  Content-Length: 240
  Content-Type: application/json
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Authorization: Basic cmthbmc6Um9LYTEyMyE=
  Connection: close
Response headers
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2011 18:55:23 GMT
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1uxr8b377s5xs;Path=/
```

Answer (score 1):

JAXBException is in this xml namespace (*javax.xml.bind.JAXBException*).

Are you trying to parse JSON as XML?

Comment: Thanks for coming back :D Definitely JSON, as specified with my annotation on server side: @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).

Comment: So how is an XML exception being thrown - what's the stack trace on the server?

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON

```
{
  metaData =     {
    name = "test.txt";
    remoteKey = 4;
    remoteShare = test1;
};
}
```

Did you mean :

```
{
  "metaData": {
    "name":"test.txt",
    "remoteKey":"4",
    "remoteShare":"test1"
  }
}
```

(If you did, update your question and I'll delete this answer ;)

Comment: Ye, I just used a parser to clear out the structure. I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just paste in the _actual_ string from the server so we can see why the parser is throwing errors?

Comment: I was not able to intercept the request body at the server side. I tried with Fiddler, but not sure why it doesn't intercept anything. But I did try to intercept the request at client side. Request header and request body are properly set up.

Comment: What does your jsonMetadata look like?

Comment: It's just like posted. A plain text format of json. I was able to sniffer the packets at server side with Wireshark. It looks perfectly fine.